# Different Springboot services using a same tables

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, microservices, spring-jdbc

We have a running Springboot service `A` that created some relational entities using Spring JPA with Hibernate ORM.
We need to create a new Springboot service `B` that needs to access `A`'s tables but with different queries.

There are few options I though of:

1. Making service `B` use Spring JPA and Hibernate and copy the same entity models from service `A`
   But I'm not sure if this method causes any synchronization issues caused by Hibernate's first level caching. 
   Both services will not be using 2nd level cache.
2. Same like option 1, making service `B` use Spring JPA and Hibernate but import service `A` as a dependency in service `B` instead of copying the entity models.
3. Making service `B` use Spring JdbcTemplate if we are not creating any new entities in service `B`.

I also like to know how service `B`'s table can have a unidirectional foriegn key relationship (`@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne`) with service `A`'s table.

Please suggest me which option is better or if there's a better way. 
If it is a bad pratice to use other service's tables, please suggest the correct design. \

Thanks

Comment: I would say the technology you will use is somehow irrelevant for the data consistencies etc. You should think about your use-cases. Why would you want to have 2 different services on top of the same data. As you label this question as microservices I would say it accepted as a bad practice in general. I would suggest don't do that unless you have a good reason.

Comment: To add to what @cool already mentioned, from what you describe, it sounds like the 'correct' implementation would be (1) for service A to own the data represented by A's entities, (2) for service B to own the data represented by the *additional* B's entities, (3) for the FK relationship(s) from B to A's data to be represented simply by a field holding the A entity's id (no `@OneToOne/@ManyToOne`), and (4) for B to query A for its data and perform the join in memory, whenever needed